# What is the best way to typing React Components when they styling with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am migrating a project to Typescript. I have a component styled with styled-components and I need to override it with styled-components on some other component. My component looks like this.

This component aims to render an image and if image not exist, returns a Fallback element styled with styled-components.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Fallback = styled.div`
    padding-bottom: 56%; /* 16/9 ratio */
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
`

export const Image = styled.img`
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
`

interface ImageWithFallbackProps {
    src: string
    alt: string
    fallback: typeof Fallback
}

const ImageWithFallback = ({
    src,
    alt,
    fallback = Fallback,
    ...props
}: ImageWithFallbackProps): React.ReactNode => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)
    const FallbackElement: React.FC = fallback

    if (error) return <FallbackElement />

    return <Image src={src} alt={alt} {...props} onError={() => setError(true)} />
}

export default ImageWithFallback
```

And, I use it on another component.

```
const Content: AnyStyledComponent = styled.div`
    /* styles */
`

Content.Text = styled.div`      
    font-weight: bold;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: left;
`

Content.Image = styled(ImageWithFallback)`
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 80px;
    align-self: baseline;
`

Content.Fallback = styled(Fallback)`
    width: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 54px;
`
```

But I get an error where I define Content.Image like this `Content.Image = styled(ImageWithFallback)`. Error code is ts(2769). How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How did you declare AnyStyledComponent? can you add this code too?

Comment: AnyStyledComponent comes from styled-components as a built-in feature. 

import { AnyStyledComponent } from 'styled-components'